# UITableViewContoller in UINavigationController with UISearchController wrong after back button

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller

We have a UINavigationController with a UITableViewController.  We have a UISearchController to filter the list of items in the table.  When we tap a cell it navigates to the detail.  But when we navigate back, its as if the UISearchBar is on top of the content... like instead of being in the table header, it is now over top of the table.  How can we get it to behave as being in the table header.

```
func buildSearchBar() {
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

Edit to add: we set all UINavigationBar appearance to be translucent = NO;  This is the line of code that seems to break it for us.  Does that sound right to anyone else?

```
[UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = NO;
```

Comment: You build the view programmatically or using Interface Builder?

Comment: I posted some of the code above.  The table, nav controller is in the storyboard... adding the search controller and setting the translucency is in the code.

Comment: Where in your code do you call `buildSearchBar`

Comment: in the method viewDidLoad

Comment: Try calling it in `viewWillAppear`... does that make a difference?

Comment: No it did not make a difference

Comment: Try removing `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar` from your custom method, calling buildSearchBar in `viewDidLoad`, and placing the above line in `viewWillAppear`...?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Add the following line to the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller (`self` in the code you posted in your question).

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true;
```

This fixed the problem for me.